# Can it be proved that $\frac{d}{d x} \frac{( 1 - \Phi(x)) }{\phi(x)} < 0$? (updated question with more contents)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, normal-distribution

Let $\phi(x) = \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{- \frac 12 x^2}$ and $\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x \phi(t)dt$ be the PDF and CDF of the standard normal distribution.

Can it be proved that
$$ \frac{d}{d x} \frac{( 1 - \Phi(x)) }{\phi(x)} < 0 \ ?$$

To show that i find
$$ \frac{d}{d x} \frac{( 1 - \Phi(x)) }{\phi(x)}  = \frac{-\phi(x)^2 -[-x \phi(x) ( 1 - \Phi(x)) ]}{\phi(x)^2} \ $$

which is

$$ \frac{d}{d x} \frac{( 1 - \Phi(x)) }{\phi(x)}  = \frac{-\phi(x) +[x  ( 1 - \Phi(x)) ]}{\phi(x)} \ $$
and 
$$ \frac{d}{d x} \frac{( 1 - \Phi(x)) }{\phi(x)}  = \frac{x  ( 1 - \Phi(x)) }{\phi(x)} -1 \ $$

So we need to prove

$$\frac{x  ( 1 - \Phi(x)) }{\phi(x)} -1 < 0 \ $$

which is

$$\  1 - \Phi(x)  < \frac{1 }{x} \phi(x) \ $$

And by following @kavi-rama-murthy proof at the accepted answer below, it is proved. Thanks @kavi-rama-murthy

Comment: Compute the derivatives and see what you end up with!

Comment: At least i would like to prove for x>0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int_x ^{\infty} e^{-t^{2}/2} \, dt =\int_x ^{\infty} t \frac 1 t e^{-t^{2}/2} \, dt <\frac 1   x \int_x ^{\infty} t  e^{-t^{2}/2} \, dt = \frac 1 x e^{-x^{2}/2}$ so $1-\Phi (x) < \frac 1 x  \phi (x)$ This proves teh inequality you are looking for.

Comment: If you could just add some description about how you proved 1−Φ(x)<1/xϕ(x), it would be fantastic.

Comment: In the first step I multiplied and divided by $t$. Then I used that fact that $\frac 1 t <\frac 1 x$ for $x<t<\infty $. In the next step I evaluated the integral of $te^{-t^{2}/2}$ explicitly by noting that its antiderivative is $-e^{-t^{2}/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this hence the graph[image]

Comment: Is this a proof ?

Comment: Dear @ClaudeLeibovici a simple proof then can be followed by the graph. It's just due to calculus knowledge